# iOS Crashlytics crash log shows _hidden even after upload the bitcode dSYM to fabric

Tags: ios, crash-reports, crashlytics, bitcode

I've been investigating the crash in our app for quite a while, and I still can't figure out why Crashlytics cannot symbolicate some of the crashes (3 to be specific). These are actually the current major crashes of the app and we are desperately looking for any hint possible.

Our app has bitcode enabled and opt-in uploading dSYM to Apple. I tried to read through the Crashlytics doc [All about Missing dSYMs](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html), manually download the dSYM zip from iTunesConnect, uploaded it to fabric. The "hidden" crash number keeps growing afterwards, and the problem is, we never get a missing dSYM warning in fabric and it's not showing the dSYM missing in the [fabric settings page](https://fabric.io/settings/apps) for the app build we are trying to investigate.

The stack trace is like this:
[Crash stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4daI.png)

Any helps and suggestions would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why the symbolication failed. But from looking at your crash report, a few things come into my mind, maybe they can help you somehow.

The crash happens inside a closure which uses UIWebView somehow. After doing something with javascript, resources are being freed, this is then when the crash happens. You can check the last code called here:

https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/f43689c3ed50cd00bf76d5731983046b988e6efa/Source/WebCore/loader/cache/CachedResource.cpp

Nothing fancy going on there.

My guess is, that input vars of the closure are freed to early. Even if you are blind, without a working symbolication, you could try to find closures initiating JavaScript calls and check for this conditions e.g. `[unowned self] in` or similar and try pass them in owned. This could obviously lead to leaking memory, but you can test this before releasing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem for tracking it down is, the only part our app is using a UIWebView is the DFP ad, which I’m totally blind about the implementation. That’s why I want to get the symbolicated crash log and maybe discuss with their SDK team.

Comment: You say blind, this means no source? But is this not then the reason for your symbolication problems? Sorry for the maybe stupid comment, don't know which SDK you are really using...

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?